# I cant get the link, which was created by a JS script, to download the zip file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm parsing the webpage to get download links to files, and save them to some database.

How can I get a link, with Python 3 and Selenium, if it's created by JS code, after a click event? (there are no links in the HTML DOM).

So, I can get it with [the Mozilla browser](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) in Downloads, but I can't get to that in my code.

Comment: can u post the webpage url or the inspect element data of it?

Comment: @IslamTaha, <a href=javascript:dnn('LUHPGPJO') class=fn9>DNS-1100-04_A1_FW_1.01.zip</a>